# Can ionic app support different versions installation in a single app

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3, code-push

I have an app that can connect to different servers which needs different app versions. Thus I need to **support different versions installation in a single app**.

Is it even possible to somehow:

(1) Retrieve the related version files from each server and store on phone

(2) Install each version ONLY once

(3) When connected to respective server, run the required version

Researched about `ionic deploy`, `code-push`, `hot-code-push` etc but so far, an app seems to be able to install only a single version each time. Just asking in case I am missing anything.